# projectile takes up 1 GB and makes everything slow

Tags: projectile, performance

I added projectile a while back and it makes emacs bloat up memory from 25mb to about 1.16 GB and everything becomes very slow (loding emacs, saving files, opening new files, etc).

I think it may be because it loaded everything in my home directory as part of projectile. I'm not sure. Any ideas on what I can do?

Is there a way to see what is being loaded? I've tried projectile-invalidate-cache but it didn't have any effect.

Here's what I added to my init.el file

```lisp
;; We need something to manage the various projects we work on
;; and for common functionality like project-wide searching, fuzzy file finding etc.
(use-package projectile
  :init
  (projectile-mode t) ;; Enable this immediately
  :config
  (setq projectile-enable-caching t ;; Much better performance on large projects
i        projectile-completion-system 'ivy)) ;; Ideally the minibuffer should aways look similar

;; Counsel and projectile should work together.
(use-package counsel-projectile
  :init
  (counsel-projectile-mode))
```